# How do the auto-route generated routing rules work

Tags: linux, go, networking, router, policy

I'm a user of the clash.meta project, which depends on  sing-tun project. I'm having some trouble understanding how the auto-route feature works in my configuration. Could you please explain the purpose of the generated routing rules?

Here's an example of my configuration file:

```
tun:
  enable: true
  stack: gvisor
  dns-hijack:
    - any:53
  auto-route: true
  auto-detect-interface: true
```

And here's an example of the generated routing rules:

```bash
❯ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
9000:   from all to 198.18.0.0/30 lookup 2022
9001:   from all ipproto icmp goto 9010
9002:   not from all dport 53 lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
9002:   not from all iif lo lookup 2022
9002:   from 0.0.0.0 iif lo lookup 2022
9002:   from 198.18.0.0/30 iif lo lookup 2022
9010:   from all nop
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
❯ ip route show table 2022
default dev Meta 
❯ ip route show table main
default via 172.26.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp src 172.26.1.105 metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.26.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.105 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
198.18.0.0/30 dev Meta proto kernel scope link src 198.18.0.1 
❯ ip route show table local
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
local 172.26.1.105 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope host src 172.26.1.105 
broadcast 172.26.1.255 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.1.105 
local 192.168.122.1 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.255 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local 198.18.0.1 dev Meta proto kernel scope host src 198.18.0.1 
broadcast 198.18.0.3 dev Meta proto kernel scope link src 198.18.0.1
```

```
❯ ip route get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 dev Meta table 2022 src 198.18.0.1 uid 1000 
    cache
```

why?